# How to compile C++ program AND using GLIB library?

Tags: c++, c, migration, glib

I was given a **C** library. I was also given some **C** executables built on the aforementioned library. Both the library source code and the executables source code make use of GLIB library. Everything works fine but I was asked (among other stuff) to migrate the library and executables code to C++ as the development environment that I'm going to have to use only compile through g++ and not gcc (this is not an option unfortunately). However, migration for this code was not a difficult task at all but I can't rid of the error raised inside GLIB function calls. They are almost all implicit conversions that C++ does not support but the point is that I cannot (and I don't want) to edit GLIB library. I "solved" these problems using `-fpermissive` compiler flag but I definitely would like to avoid it.
Fot as I see it I have three choises:

1. Keep using `-fpermissive` (bad)
2. Find a way to keep using GLIB without `-fpermissive` flag
3. Substitute GLIB function calls with STL function

I would go through option 3 but I'm out of time, then I ask you if there is some means to go through option 2

I don't know what lines of code I should report but perhaps the more appropriate ones are the compiler and linker flags of my makefile:

```
CFLAGS  = -O3 -Wall -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pbc -I/usr/local/include/pbc
LDFLAGS = -O3 -Wall -lglib-2.0 -lgmp -lpbc -lcrypto
```

Comment: Definitely add a `-Werror=return-type` to your options as not returning a value from a function may be valid C but it is apocalyptic levels of bad in C++. Not sure what your exact requirements are, would you be permitted to use `g++ -x c` (which is a circuitous way of saying gcc) ?

Comment: Priority one: the requirements are bad, change them. If that is not possible, the result will be at least as bad as the requirements, I would focus on "does it work?" and torture it under valgrind for a bit to catch the worst horrors. If you need `-fpermissive` to make it go, sure, why not.

Comment: My requirements are: given a C library and C source code for executables, migrate them in C++. Is it easy? Extremely easy, but GLIB function calls raise invalid conversion errors unless I do not use `-fpermissive` flag

Comment: By the way `-x c` option worked fine, I will consider it. Thanks